# Как менять цвет когда таймер меньше 10 минут и возвращать когда больше?

Tags: html, css

а как сделать чтобы цвет менялся не на 5 секунд, и не на 5 секунд, а когда таймер будет менее чем на 10 минутах. Есть таймеры ивентов, и нужно чтобы когда было менее 10 минут цвет менялся на крассный, а когда время истечет то возвращался обратно.

Допустим есть список ивентов:
День рождение: 20м32с
Новый год: 15м53с
Аванс: 4м45с

Нужно чтоб у аванса был красный, а у остальных обычный, но когда у аванса закончится 4м45с и появится новый допустим: 1д 23ч 45м 4с. Возвращать исходный цвет.

Евенты выводятся с помощью

`<div><span>Аванс</span><small id="event1">43м 16с</small></div>`

Comment: ссылка на вопрос, по мотивам которого задан данный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981298/178576